# How can I generate a random number with a specific distribution and primitive type in Julia?

Tags: julia

For example, generating a matrix with a standard normal distribution, every single number has the Float32 type:

```
rand(Normal(0,1), Float32, (2, 3))
```

And it throws a MethodError:

> MethodError: no method matching rand(::Normal{Float64}, ::Type{Float32}, ::Tuple{Int64, Int64})

But `rand(Normal(0,1), (2, 3))` works well.

What is the correct way?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are using `Normal` from Distributions.jl, you just need to pass `Float32` values (e.g., `Float32(1)` or `1f0`) as arguments to the distribution.

```
julia> rand(Normal(0f0, 1f0), (2,3))
2×3 Matrix{Float32}:
  0.360488   0.570298  -1.1475
 -0.551529  -0.899998   0.120817
```

Comment: This is the correct answer but note that this is a peculiarity of `Normal` and you shouldn't expect this to work for all distributions, see https://github.com/JuliaStats/Distributions.jl/issues/1071 for a discussion.